# how do I install 12.04?

Tags: system-installation

I'm running 10.04 and want to upgrade.

I've downloaded 12.04 to my machine (not a disc) and can't get it installed.

How do I get it installed?

Comment: What do you mean by "...and can't get it installed."? Why not? What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily upgrade over the network with the following procedure.

1. Launch the update manager.
2. Click the Check button to check for new updates.
3. If there are any updates to install, use the Install Updates button to install them,   and press Check again after that is complete.
4. A message will appear informing you of the availability of the new release.

For 10.04LTS users you need to check the "Release upgrade - Show new distribution releases" drop-down to make sure "Long term support releases only" is selected, and change it if otherwise. See the Trouble-shooting section below for more details. Please see the trouble-shooting section for the special case for LTS users between 12.04 and the release 12.04.1

1. Click Upgrade.
2. Follow the on-screen instructions.

See Also:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PreciseUpgrades for more information on some alternate methods of upgrading for certain cases.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a fresh install or an upgrade? In any case you need to make a startup USB disk from the iso file you've downloaded using usb-creator-gtk. I suggest you back up your home folder and make a fresh install using a startup disk. (You will have to install your applications afresh but backing up the home folder enables you to save the settings.)